# How to install surface mount box under eave with aluminum covering

Tags: electrical, lighting

I want to install a flood light under the eave of my house. I ran the electric from the basement through 2 floors to the third floor attic and into the eave already. I bought the flood light and a round surface mount box.

I asked a guy at Home Depot about the install and showed him this pic I took:

[image: eave]

He seemed to know what he was talking about, but didn't mention anything about the eave covering. I then looked up how to do the install on YouTube when I got home and the first video I saw said to not install when the eave has a ridged covering with channels for airflow, which is what it looks like I have. The claim was that this could cause water to get into the box:

https://youtu.be/SQxaWKmGbIw

Should I abandon this little project or can I like, cut a hole in the either aluminum (or vinyl? - I'm guessing aluminum because that's what the garage has) covering to mount the electrical box?

This is the type of box I got:

- Round Bronze Weatherproof Box with Five 1/2 in. Threaded Outlets

https://www.homedepot.com/p/204208043

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He has an old work box. You have exterior grade; you can put that wherever you want. If you're worried, use dope on the knock-out plugs and the fitting.

Drill a hole in the eve right up against a joist (1" hole saw, or however big it needs to be to *actually* fit the fitting - it's always bigger than you think). Put the wire through the hole and into the rear KO, then angle your screws to grab the joist. Or add some framing to catch a screw from the other eyelet. I wouldn't caulk anything.

In the future, always plan the end point before you begin.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! That's good to hear. I have a couple follow up questions. If I can install on top of this instead of cut a hole (as I'd imagined), how to I keep from warping/dimpling the aluminum from the compression? Also, I'm guessing there exist air-tight wire clamps in the box to get the wire through the KO without worrying about water getting in? And any tips on finding the joist through the aluminum - normally, I would knock the ceiling and listen for it. Can't imagine that technique would work here. I guess I could drill a hole and use my scope camera.

Comment: Could you explain further what you mean by "add some framing". I assume you mean some metal piece that I can both screw to the eyelet and into the joist?

Comment: @hepcat72 - I was going to mention: don't screw it down so hard that you smash the siding. Also assumed you had access from the attic. And that you're using EMT, BX, or water-tight (probably Romex, eh? *That* you might want to caulk). But if you're worried about water where it isn't supposed to be anyway, then that's a gutter problem. - It's flexible enough that you should get a pretty good idea where a joist is from pushing on it. (I won't tell anybody if you only get one screw in an eyelet ;) ... to add some framing you need attic access.

Comment: Ah. Right. The attic is partially finished. I took up a couple of floor boards and am installing an outlet at the same time, which allowed me to feed the wire. I was planning to get one screw into a joist and I have an expanding anchor for the other (though with the gap the aluminum creates, that might not work. Finding the joist seems to be the part I'm most unsure about. My scope camera doesn't turn on its own.

Comment: I assume that the aluminum is covering wood? I won't be able to tell until I rent a 28' ladder. I peered around from the attic using my scope, but the color isn't good enough to be able to tell. I can try pushing to see if I can find the joist. Hopefully, I won't have to drill multiple times to find it.

Comment: @hepcat72 - they make siding removal tools, but I'd try to avoid that. Bend a piece of wire into a half loop and stick it into one of the air slots until you touch it? You could be off like an inch and still be able spin the box so that an eyelet lines up. Or pick a spot where there definitely isn't a joist and use two toggle bolts (not if it's vinyl though; kinda a schlocky thing to do even in aluminum).

Comment: That all being said, you sure about the throw from a third story? Usually these are at about 10' up (the length of an EMT) from where you penetrate. Then you don't need to rent a stupidly large ladder to change the fixture in the future.

Comment: Yeah. I measured it yesterday. My house is an American foursquare (built in 1920). The 3' overhang eave is 22' off the ground.

Comment: And I google how tall of a ladder is needed for that. My extension ladder is only 18', so at an angle, it at best gets me 16' up the wall.

Comment: And the light is a 5000 lumen LED that should last multiple decades.